# 2021 Developers Survey does not let you go back to fix incorrect answers?

Tags: bug, survey-2021

As the title say, the survey does not let you go back a step to correct an incorrect answer. Somehow I selected the wrong location and as soon as I went ahead realized the mistake.

It seems that the list of states scrolls down 1 option when you hover over the bottom option, causing a mis-click one item down from what you meant to select.

This seems like undesirable behavior?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pennsylvania's a nice state.  Workaround:  Move there.

Comment: Perhaps they are using that feature to collect [ohnoseconds](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ohnosecond)?

Comment: *"This seems like undesirable behavior?"* - You are describing two different things, though: Which one is this Q&A about? (As an aside, I recall having gone back in the survey to correct an answer. I believe it was as simple as using the browser's back button.)

Comment: @IInspectable I remember trying that on many kinds of surveys, with various results. Usually, it told me that my session is expired or that I already replied to that question. Though I never tried that on a Stack Overflow survey yet.

Comment: Anywon hoo iz *anywun* onn Stackh Overfloh nevur maeks uh misteak. Shurly u noe dhaht?

Comment: @AndrewMorton https://youtu.be/X6NJkWbM1xk

Comment: @IInspectable The survey does not change the path, that or it replaces it instead of pushing history. There is no previous URL to go back to at that stage. Revisiting it fresh brings you back to that spot.

As for what is the undesirable behavior, hopefully the title of the question provides a hint for that....